# Java Get Zip file content

Tags: java, file, zip

My problem is that I want to see if a file is in a zip file. So I have made this code :

```
File zipf = new File(backupFolder, dfws.format(new Date()) + ".zip");
                        if (!zipf.exists()) zipf.createNewFile();
                        fs = new FileOutputStream(zipf);
                        ZipOutputStream zos = new ZipOutputStream(fs);
                        System.out.println("size : " + zipf.length());
                        if (zipf.length() > 0) {
                            ZipFile zf = new ZipFile(zipf);

                            System.out.println("entry : " + zf.getEntry(name));
                            if (zf.getEntry(name) != null) {
                                int index = 1;
                                while (zf.getEntry(index + "_" + name) != null) {
                                    index++;
                                }
                                name = index + "_" + name;
                            }

                            zf.close();
                        }
                        System.out.println("index found : " + name);
```

But the problem is that the length of the file is always 0. And I can't create an instance of ZipFile if the zip file doesn't have files inside.

Comment: Does the file exist before line 2 in your snippet? If it doesn't, then a new empty file is created, which may explain why it has a length of 0.

Comment: You are opening a `FileOutputStream` on that `File`. This means you are trying to *write* to it, and it truncates the file as soon as you do this. If you want to read from it, just create the `ZipFile` object without that `FileOutputStream` part.

Comment: The `exists()` and  `createNewFile()` calls are redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to RealSkeptic : I had to open the FileOutputStream after creating the ZipFile.

Comment: I don't understand why you're doing it at all. Is the intent really to destroy the zip file? And produce an empty file?